# what is a best approach to reduce the redux state size?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I have a new project about mobile app using react native tech.

I am thinking about using redux to manage the whole data from remote server api. our product have more business data need to display in mobile app.

So, My question is: redux state store our business data and it will take more memory on mobile device, like a ListView component. how can i solve this problem if i want to reduce the memory usage?

Comment: It's not a real problem yet, but an imaginary one. Imaginary problems are solved by imagination - just hold your breath and imagine that it's resolved.

Comment: if some info is not used at all, why keep it in your state?

Comment: @zerkms It's not an "imaginary" problem it's a hypothetical one.  Do you agree that hypothetical problems are valuably discussed ahead of being concrete problems so you can determine whether the general idea behind the approach is valid before you make the effort of implementation?  I agree though the question could be better formulated. :)

Comment: Oh, and I should also say that I agree with you in the sense that this is not a reasonable issue to be concerned about.

Comment: @AdamTerlson I cannot agree that imaginary or hypothetical issues should be considered **BEFORE** any experiments/investigation. In 99% of cases the predictions about performance bottlenecks are wrong, so why bother predicting?

Comment: @zerkms I probably misread your intent, that's my fault. We agree, homework should be done to have a reasonable perspective of what is an important factor to consider. My initial reading led me to think you were saying because it's not presently a performance issue that the discussion (about the former specifically) wasn't worth having yet. Cheers mate, my bad.

Answer (score 6):

I am choosing, based on your background description of what you're trying to do, to address the underlying concern about the size of your redux store generally and the approach of storing everything on the client in my answer, and will not address specifically how to actually reduce the size of your data store here (the only answer to that is simply "don't store so much").

**This is just a total swag and ignores things like compression, data duplication, the difference between storing something in AsyncStorage vs simply being in memory, etc.**

That having been said, if you need some sort of gut check on whether memory/storage will be an issue, take a representative chunk of record data served by your API, serialize it as a JSON string, and figure out how big it is.

For example, this [example twitter response](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets) is roughly 8.5 KB with whitespace removed.  Let's say 10KB for each individual record for simplicity.

Now, how many records do you plan on bringing down?  10?  100?  1000?  Let's say 1000 records of this type.  That's 10,000KB or roughly 10MB.

With the constructs here, 10 MB is (Edit: depending on the specific constraint you're concerned about, may or may not be) a trivial amount of memory/storage to use in your application.

You need to do this similar process to your particular use case, and see if the amount of data you wish to store will be a problem for the devices you have to support.

A more relevant thing to consider is the performance impact of churning through large quantities of data on a single thread to do things like data manipulation, joining/merging, etc if that will be a need.

Redux is a tiny library that doesn't actually do that much for you by itself.  This consideration is a general one, and is totally unique to your own application and cannot be concretely answered.

Comment: Oh, that's a hypothetical problem of hosting 10Mb of data. That is a *problem* indeed. (+1 though :-P )

Comment: Now seriously: your answer perfectly aligns with my point: investigate and solve when it becomes a *real* problem. So... :-)

Comment: @zerkms yup. We are "violently" in agreement. :)

Comment: @zerkms re 10mb, see above